# Tensorflow: I get something wrong in accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just run a simple code and want to get accuracy after training. I load the model that I saved, but when I want to get accuracy, I get something wrong. Why?

```
# coding=utf-8
from  color_1 import read_and_decode, get_batch, get_test_batch
import AlexNet
import cv2
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import AlexNet_train
import math

batch_size=128
num_examples = 1000
crop_size=56

def evaluate(test_x, test_y):
    image_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 56, 56, 3], name='x-input')
    label_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size], name='y-input')

    y = AlexNet.inference(image_holder,evaluate,None)

    correct_prediction=tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),tf.argmax(label_holder,1))
    accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        sess.run(init_op)
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
        ckpt=tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(AlexNet_train.MODEL_SAVE_PATH)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            ckpt_name = os.path.basename(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
            saver.restore(sess, os.path.join(AlexNet_train.MODEL_SAVE_PATH, ckpt_name))
            print('Loading success, global_step is %s' % global_step)
            step=0

            image_batch, label_batch = sess.run([test_x, test_y])
            accuracy_score=sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={image_holder: image_batch,
                                                              label_holder: label_batch})
            print("After %s training step(s),validation "
                  "precision=%g" % (global_step, accuracy_score))
        coord.request_stop()  
        coord.join(threads)

def main(argv=None):
    test_image, test_label = read_and_decode('val.tfrecords')

    test_images, test_labels = get_test_batch(test_image, test_label, batch_size, crop_size)

    evaluate(test_images, test_labels)


if __name__=='__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

And here is error,it said that this line in my code is wrong:" correct_prediction=tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),tf.argmax(label_holder,1))"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/AlexNet/Alex_save/AlexNet_test.py", line 80, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/AlexNet/Alex_save/AlexNet_test.py", line 76, in main
    evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/AlexNet/Alex_save/AlexNet_test.py", line 45, in evaluate
    label_holder: label_batch})
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected dimension in the range [-1, 1), but got 1
     [[Node: ArgMax_1 = ArgMax[T=DT_INT32, Tidx=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_y-input_0, ArgMax_1/dimension)]]

Caused by op u'ArgMax_1', defined at:
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/AlexNet/Alex_save/AlexNet_test.py", line 80, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/AlexNet/Alex_save/AlexNet_test.py", line 76, in main
    evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/AlexNet/Alex_save/AlexNet_test.py", line 22, in evaluate
    correct_prediction=tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),tf.argmax(label_holder,1))
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 263, in argmax
    return gen_math_ops.arg_max(input, axis, name)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 168, in arg_max
    name=name)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2395, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1264, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected dimension in the range [-1, 1), but got 1
     [[Node: ArgMax_1 = ArgMax[T=DT_INT32, Tidx=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_y-input_0, ArgMax_1/dimension)]]
```

How to solve it?

Comment: It seems wrong in line " accuracy_score=sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={image_holder: image_batch,label_holder: label_batch}) ". but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: What about the thing the error message tells you? It straight up says that arg_max argument needs to be in the range [-1, 1), but you're passing 1, which is invalid.

Does fixing that not work or did you just not read the error message?

Comment: of course I know the error, I just don't know how to solve. I am not good in this . so can you tell me how to solve it ? should I add something ?

Comment: Well, the error message tells you to pass something that is not the number 1, and you're passing the number 1. One possible solution would be to pass something that is not the number 1 (and even better, something that actually IS in the range [-1,1), for example, 0.5, or 0.9 or whatever. I don't know what that argument actually does so I don't know the best number to put, but you can at least see if it fixes your error.

Comment: e...I saw the usage of the 'tf.equal' and 'tf.argmax' ,but it seem that it has no limit in number .so I feel confused . what I input is image and size is [56,56,3], and 'y' is the output of fully connect layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47391375/3214872) related to the problem here:

[`tf.argmax`'s definition](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/argmax) states:

> axis: A Tensor. Must be one of the following types: int32, int64.
>   int32, **0 <= axis < rank(input)**. Describes which axis of the input
>   Tensor to reduce across.

It seems, then, that the only way to run `argmax` on the last axis of the tensor is by giving it `axis=-1`, because of the "strictly less than" sign in the definition of the function.