# InvalidArgumentError: Expected dimension in the range [-1, 1) but got 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, image-recognition, data-science

I'm not sure what this error means.  This error occurs when I try to calculate `acc`:

```
acc = accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {x: batch_images, y: batch_labels, keep_prob: 1.0})
```

I've tried looking up solutions, but I couldn't find any online.  Any ideas on what's causing my error?

Here's a [link to my full code](https://github.com/mdlee6/svhn/blob/master/multidigit_prediction.ipynb).

Comment: Try `keep_prob: 0.98` instead.

Comment: `[]` and `()` differ in whether the endpoint is inclusive. Thus, the syntax above indicates that `-1` is a valid value, but `1` is not.

Comment: Huh. We've got at least one [other instance of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581910/tensorflow-i-get-something-wrong-in-accuracy-does-anybody-know-whats-going-on), but without an answer; one or the other will need to be answered before we can dupe 'em out.

Comment: I thought the error was saying that the variable `acc` which is the tensor `accuracy` being evaluated, has a dimension of 1, but it should be within the range [-1, 1).

What does it mean to have [-1, 1) dimensions?

Comment: Maybe this is the same problem
Hope to be helpful
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377214/runtimeerror-dimension-out-of-range-expected-to-be-in-range-of-1-0-but-go)

Comment: Maybe this is the same problem
Hope to be helpful [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377214/runtimeerror-dimension-out-of-range-expected-to-be-in-range-of-1-0-but-go)

Answer (score 3):

For the people coming for **Tensorflow serving** or **Estimator loading**, this error occurs because the values in the feature dictionary need to be in batches.

```
data = {
        "signature_name": "predict",
        "inputs": {k:[v] for k,v in inputs.items()}
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The source code generating this error reads as follows:

```
OP_REQUIRES(context, axis >= 0 && axis < input_dims,
            errors::InvalidArgument("Expected dimension in the range [",
                                    -input_dims, ", ", input_dims,
                                    "), but got ", dim));
```

Note that `axis` is required to be **less than** `input_dims`, **not less-than-or-equal**.

This conforms with the syntax `[-1,1)` in the message: `[` indicates an inclusive value (such that `-1` is valid), whereas `)` indicates an exclusive value (putting `1` itself outside the range).

Comment: So does that mean that the dimensions of `acc` is 1, but it should be within the range [-1, 1)?  What does it mean to have dimensions within that range?

Comment: @mdlee6, equal to or greater than -1, less than 1.

Comment: yeah so the expected dimensions is supposed to be equal to or greater than -1, less than 1, but the dimension of `acc` came out to 1.  What does it mean to have a dimension equal to or greater than -1, less than 1?

Comment: Stumbled upon this. Am I the only one thinking having to use `-1` instead of the index of the last dimension, if that is known, is extremely counter-intuitive?

Comment: Yeah somebody needs to update this exception message. It is very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error but the problem for me was that I was trying to use argmax on a 1 dimensional vector. So the shape of my label was (50,) and I was trying to do a tf.argmax(y,1) on that when evaluating. The solution reference is [Tensorflow: I get something wrong in accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581910/tensorflow-i-get-something-wrong-in-accuracy)

Answer (score 0):

For code like

```
tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
```

which is often used when calculating accuracy, you can change to

```
tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, -1), tf.argmax(labels, -1))
```

according to the source code:

```
// tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/index_ops_cpu.cc:58
OP_REQUIRES(ctx, axis >= 0 && axis < input_dims,
            errors::InvalidArgument("Expected dimension in the range [",
                                    -input_dims, ", ", input_dims,
                                    "), but got ", dim));
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem.
Check the expression of batch_labels

```
# if use one hot code use
# y_true_cls = tf.argmax(y_true, dimension=1)

# if not one hot code use
y_true_cls = y_true
```

Hope to be helpful

Comment: This does not give the answer to the question and your link is not accessible for anyone to see. The correct answer to this question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581910/tensorflow-i-get-something-wrong-in-accuracy