# How to predict a specific image using Mnist

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow, and I think I got the right answer, but I am missing something minimal, that I cant find online. I hope someone send me a reference or leads me to what I am missing.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
batch_size = 128
test_size = 256

def init_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01))

def model(X, w, w2, w3, w4, w_o, p_keep_conv, p_keep_hidden):
    l1a = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(X, w,                       # l1a shape=(?, 28, 28, 32)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l1 = tf.nn.max_pool(l1a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],              # l1 shape=(?, 14, 14, 32)
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    l1 = tf.nn.dropout(l1, p_keep_conv)

    l2a = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(l1, w2,                     # l2a shape=(?, 14, 14, 64)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l2 = tf.nn.max_pool(l2a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],              # l2 shape=(?, 7, 7, 64)
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    l2 = tf.nn.dropout(l2, p_keep_conv)

    l3a = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(l2, w3,                     # l3a shape=(?, 7, 7, 128)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l3 = tf.nn.max_pool(l3a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],              # l3 shape=(?, 4, 4, 128)
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    l3 = tf.reshape(l3, [-1, w4.get_shape().as_list()[0]])    # reshape to (?, 2048)
    l3 = tf.nn.dropout(l3, p_keep_conv)

    l4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(l3, w4))
    l4 = tf.nn.dropout(l4, p_keep_hidden)

    pyx = tf.matmul(l4, w_o)
    return pyx

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
trX, trY, teX, teY = mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels, mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels
trX = trX.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)  # 28x28x1 input img
teX = teX.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)  # 28x28x1 input img
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 28, 28, 1])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 10])

w = init_weights([3, 3, 1, 32])       # 3x3x1 conv, 32 outputs
w2 = init_weights([3, 3, 32, 64])     # 3x3x32 conv, 64 outputs
w3 = init_weights([3, 3, 64, 128])    # 3x3x32 conv, 128 outputs
w4 = init_weights([128 * 4 * 4, 625]) # FC 128 * 4 * 4 inputs, 625 outputs
w_o = init_weights([625, 10])         # FC 625 inputs, 10 outputs (labels)

p_keep_conv = tf.placeholder("float")
p_keep_hidden = tf.placeholder("float")
py_x = model(X, w, w2, w3, w4, w_o, p_keep_conv, p_keep_hidden)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=py_x, labels=Y))
train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001, 0.9).minimize(cost)
predict_op = tf.argmax(py_x, 1)
# Launch the graph in a session
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # you need to initialize all variables
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for i in range(100):
        training_batch = zip(range(0, len(trX), batch_size),
                             range(batch_size, len(trX)+1, batch_size))
        for start, end in training_batch:
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end],
                                          p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})

        test_indices = np.arange(len(teX)) # Get A Test Batch
        np.random.shuffle(test_indices)
        test_indices = test_indices[0:test_size]

        print(i, np.mean(np.argmax(teY[test_indices], axis=1) ==
                         sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={X: teX[test_indices],
                                                         Y: teY[test_indices],
                                                         p_keep_conv: 1.0,
                                                         p_keep_hidden: 1.0})))
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "tmp/model.ckpt")
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

After all of this, now I am trying to predict a single image from this array just as an example (I know its not a proper test), to give me the class using:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Restore variables from disk.
    saver.restore(sess, "tmp/model.ckpt")
    print "...Model Loaded..."   
    prediction=tf.argmax(predict_op,1)
    print prediction.eval(feed_dict={X: teX[2].reshape(1,28,28,1)}, session=sess)
```

But im getting this error:

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
>   'Placeholder_3' with dtype

This previous problem has been solved by adding p_keep_conv: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0 to the dict.

After this another issue appeared:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-3e9ead14a8b3> in <module>()
      4     print "...Model Loaded..."
      5     prediction=tf.argmax(predict_op,1)
----> 6     classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(predict_op, 1), feed_dict={X: teX[3].reshape(1,28,28,1),p_keep_conv: 1.0,p_keep_hidden: 1.0})
      7 

....

InvalidArgumentError: Expected dimension in the range [-1, 1), but got 1
     [[Node: ArgMax_21 = ArgMax[T=DT_INT64, Tidx=DT_INT32, output_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ArgMax/_37, ArgMax_21/dimension)]]
```

Comment: You're getting the error because in your `prediction.eval()` call yo're not passing a value for `p_keep_conv` and `p_keep_hidden`. Add those to the `feed_dict` and your error will go away.
As a side note, whenever you define a `placeholder`, you should give it a name via `name='my_input'`, because otherwise it will take the default `Placeholder_N` name (like in this case). Debugging error messages is much easier with named placeholders.

Comment: That makes sense! I got another error after fixing the previous, InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected dimension in the range [-1, 1), but got 1

Comment: Please add that to the question (with the traceback and the point where the error occurs)

Comment: Done I made the edit

Comment: Can you try using `tf.argmax(predict_op,-1)` instead of what you have at the moment and see if that works?

Comment: worked! But why did this work, any link to documentation?

Comment: I'm putting everything together in an answer, plus links and explanation ;)

Comment: btw, when i print classification it gives me zero for any image I enter.

Comment: That's  whole new problem that probably deserves a new question in itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159390/discussion-between-masterwizard-and-gphilo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm summing up what we said in the comments in this answer.

#### Placeholder error:

Your `prediction.eval()` call has a `feed_dict` that doesn't contain a value for `p_keep_conv` and `p_keep_hidden`. Note that, since you don't provide a `name=...` argument whe defining your placholders, they get the default name `Placeholder_N` which is what the error message shows. It's a good practice to always give a meaningful name to variables, constants and placeholders in order to make debugging easier.

#### Argmax expected dimension:

[`tf.argmax`'s definition](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/argmax) states:

> axis: A Tensor. Must be one of the following types: int32, int64.
>   int32, **0 <= axis < rank(input)**. Describes which axis of the input
>   Tensor to reduce across.

It seems, then, that the only way to run `argmax` on the last axis of the tensor is by giving it `axis=-1`, because of the "strictly less than" sign in the definition of the function (I don't understand why they made this design choice).